# Reverse for 'results' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$']

Tags: python, django

I started on the generic views section of the Django tutorial on their website and i keep getting this error. I know this question has been asked before but these answer did not fix my issue. I was wondering could any see the error? I have removed imports to tidy the code.

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), 
    name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

views.py:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    return Questions.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Questions
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Questions
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'


def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Questions, pk=question_id)
try:
    selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
        'question': question,
        'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
    })
else:
    selected_choice.votes += 1
    selected_choice.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=
    (question.id,)))
```

detail.html:

```
<h1>{{ object.question_text }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question_id=object.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in object.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" 
    value="{{ 
    choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}
</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

results.html:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ 
    choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:results' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have named your model `Questions` instead of `Question` like the tutorial has. The detail view uses the model name in lowercase for the model instance in the template. In your case this is `questions`, which doesn't match the tutorial from the template which uses `question`.

That means that you either need to set `context_object_name` to `'question'` so that your template works:

```
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
     model = Questions
     context_object_name = 'question'
```

Or you need to change your template to use `questions` instead of `question`.

```
<h1>{{ questions.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in questions.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ 
    choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:results' questions.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

It would be a good idea to rename your model to `Question` - the standard in Django is to use the singular instead of the plural for model names. If you do this, you'll have to run `makemigrations` and then `migrate` to rename the model. If that causes problems, it might be easier to delete your migrations and database, then run `makemigrations` and `migrate` on a fresh db.

Comment: Thank you ever much worked great! First time learning Python and Django, i will change it to the correct standard, thank you very much for your advice.